# WebHDFS REST API and R

Tags: r, hadoop, webhdfs

Is there any support for using the [WebHDFS REST API](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r1.0.4/webhdfs.html) in R? Something similar to the [python package](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/WebHDFS)?

Comment: Are you sure? After a quick browse through the [source](https://github.com/RevolutionAnalytics/rhdfs/blob/master/pkg/R/hdfs.r) it looks like it depends on using hadoop java dependencies. Assuming a cluster is configured to support webhdfs it should just be a matter of setting up http:// strings and using RCurl or something similar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently there is  (from a GitHub search: https://github.com/search?q=WebHDFS+language%3AR&ref=opensearch)

https://github.com/saurfang/rwebhdfs

Haven't tested it though

Comment: I need to work around some proxy issues, but this is the sort of thing I was looking for. Thanks.

Comment: Proxy settings are exhausting, waah. I put the following lines in my `~/.Rprofile`:
```library(httr)
set_config(use_proxy(<url>, <port>, <username>, <password>))
```